# VSCode Shortcut to add strings to React react-intl

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Is there a VSCode keyboard shortcut/function to add selected text string as needed for react-intl components.

Description of workflow of the shortcut in VSCode:

1. Select a string 'foo bar' and press a shortcut key
2. The string is copied to messages constant.

```
  fooBar: {
    id: 'foo-bar',
    defaultMessage: 'Foo Bar',
  },
});
```

3. The 'foo-bar' id is inserted in the selected text.

`<FormattedMessage id={foo-bar} />`

Comment: Does the `foobar: {}` object **replace** the string `foo bar`?

Comment: Mark, I think the standard practice is to sluggify (replace spaces with dashes) and replace the string.

Comment: My testcase is representative, the full correct way of defining strings described in react I18n tutorial here https://dev.mobify.com/v2.x/how-to-guides/categories/internationalization/internationalization-and-localization-with-react-intl